# How to translate wordpress blog to other languages?

Tags: plugins, php, translation, language

I have a blog in wordpress security niche. It is currently in english and is quite popular with wordpress folks but i want to target other languages/countries as well. What would be the ideal way to do so in wordpress and how to implement the language translation and manage it with/without plugins.

Options I have:
Create a subdomain for different county eg:germany
Create a subfolder like ...com/de

How can i translate the language across these on the fly without any user interaction . Is there any way to do so in php programmatically without any use of plugin.

Suggestions would be really appreciated!!!
Find my blog here
https://secure.wphackedhelp.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with the sub directory option as it would be the best foot forward. You can integrate google translation api with wordpress in order to translate the content. Will let know in case i find something more about it.